# MySQL Inner Self Join not returning values

Tags: mysql, key, key-value

[image]

The following query references at table that has the following columns:

1. form_input_key
2. form_input_value
3. form_input_ID
4. order (associates a record with another record in the table)

SQL:

```
SELECT
   OPTION_NAME.form_input_value as option_name
   OPTION_VALUE.form_input_value as option_value
FROM 
   form_input_detail as OPTION_NAME
INNER JOIN
   form_input_detail as OPTION_VALUE 
ON OPTION_VALUE.form_input_key = 'option_value' AND 
    OPTION_VALUE.form_input_ID = OPTION_NAME.form_input_ID
WHERE
    OPTION_NAME.form_input_ID = 17 AND
    OPTION_NAME.form_input_key = 'option_name'
ORDER BY 
    OPTION_NAME.order ASC
```

After doing some research this inner self-join should return a row with the option_name and option_value in the same record, however it returns nothing.  See above image.

What I am trying to do is dynamically generate a form.  This instance would be a html select form.  The other form inputs are in a different table and I store the options in this table.  So the 'option_name' is the name the user sees in a dropdown and the option_value is the value that is submitted.

Comment: For some reason when I add a list, its un-formats the code?

Comment: Presumably, when values are inserted for the `?`, there are no matches.  That begs the question of what you are trying to do.  If you edit the question to provide sample results, there is probably another way of getting the results you are looking for.

Comment: What values do you specify for your parameters (the `?`)?

Comment: I added the values above.  The values are correct.  Something seems to be off with the join.  This is the first inner join I have done and I am still trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You must put quotes to "option_value" (on your `ON`) and to "option_name" (on your `WHERE`).

Comment: There actually are quotes, I just forgot to add them above.  I made an edit to add the quotes.  The problem persists.